# Where are the MacOS startup boot icons located?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, startup, icon

Where is the exact location of certain icons like the internal storage drive icon you often see in the startup boot manager and other boot icons like it located on MacOS?

MacOS Catalina 10.15.2

Comment: I do not think the firmware uses these files, but rather the firmware has a copy of some subset of these `.icons` files. The file [`/System/Library/Extensions/IOStorageFamily.kext/Contents/Resources/Internal.icns`](https://imgur.com/a/gI6RK7i) looks like an exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specified directories

`/System/Library/Extensions/IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily.kext/Contents/Resources/`
 and 
`/System/Library/Extensions/IOStorageFamily.kext/Contents/Resources/`

do indeed contain the .icns files used by the startup boot manager or at least it contains replicas of the .icns used.

Comment: As a new user here at Ask Different, you might not be aware that you can mark an answer as "*accepted*". This marks the answer with a green check mark. This will inform other users that an answer has been found to the posted question. It is also customary (but not required) that if you want to accept a user's comment, that you first ask the user to post an answer, then accept that answer.

Comment: Correct @DavidAnderson and also, answers should always be posted as an answer first IMO. Comments are for clarification of the post. Just like comments can be deleted, so can a premature or wrong answers once the question is clarified or changed.

Comment: That being said, the people here can sometimes be on questions that need 30 plus comments to arrive at what’s the actual problem so even a strong rule isn’t always worth following to the letter.

Answer (score -1):

In macOS you can find boot loader(boot.efi) in /System/Library/CoreServices/, you can locate boot.efi there.

Comment: Where in `boot.efi` can the startup boot icons be found?